# Memcached при ддосе тухнет?

Tags: ddos, memcached

При ддосе memcached загружает cpu 100% на 90%-100% теряется доступ к сессиям.
остальные сервисы впорядке себя чувствуют! единственная проблема с мемкешом что и после ддоса он не стабилизируется приходиться перезагружать его вручную.

Можно конечно на supervisord повешать его контроль и в случае такого ребутить но это не есть так как все сессии теряются.
В мемкеше храняться только сессии.
Конфиг:

```
PORT=0
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="32768"
CACHESIZE="4096"
OPTIONS="-L -t 8 -a 0766 -s /var/run/memcached/memcached.sock"
```

Возможно кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Очень бы не хотелось сессии держать в другом хранилище.

Comment: [off]Может без сессий для гостей можно обойтись?[/off]

Comment: В идеале да, но надо всё двигло переписать=)))